# Create a CSV file directly on an FTP server

Tags: python, csv, ftp

I have created a CSV file using the Python `csv` library.

When all the CSV files are created, my second task is to put them on an FTP server.

To achieve this, I generate all my files in the `/tmp` folder on my Linux computer, then I open an FTP connection and I upload them all to the remote server.

My question is:  It is possible to create the CSV files in the memory buffer and put them directly on my FTP server?

Comment: Can you show the code you use to generate the files, and the code you use to upload the files ?

Comment: Yes. You could probably use an `ftplib.FTP` object to do this via its `storlines()` (or `storbinary()`) method which only require a "file-like object with a readline() method" or a "file-like object with a read(num_bytes) method" respectively. See the [source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/ftplib.py) starting at about line 455 (or in the .../Lib/ftplib.py file of your Python installation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can generate files in memory using StringIO (or better cStringIO).
You can try something like this:

```
import csv
from ftplib import FTP
from cStringIO import StringIO

...
ftp = FTP(host, user, passwd)
ftp.login()
output = StringIO()
data = csv.writer(output)
data.writerow(["data"] * 5)
output.seek(0)
ftp.storbinary("STOR data.txt", output)
...
```

Please note, this isn't fully workable code and you might need some changes depending on your FTP configuration. For example, I had to add ftp.set_pasv(False) to make it work with my test FTP.

Comment: Thanks, it's perfect. Just what i needed.